# How to organize / structure methods into namespaces in a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf, namespaces

What is considered as best-pratice when it comes to organizing / structuring methods in a WCF Service?

Let's assume I have a .net dll that I want to expose through a WCF Service.

The .net dll has a namespace structure like this:

```
Root
-- > SubNameSpace1
-- > SubNameSpace2
-- > -- > CategoryA
-- > -- > CategoryB
-- > SubNameSpace3
```

How would I expose this namespace structure through a WCF Service? (Because I don't want all methods from all namespaces to be merged as methods of the client object that calls the service.)

When is it appropriate / recommend to create different *.svc files? (in relation to my namespace structure)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to not expose DLLs through services. Instead, design a service that exposes a coherent set of functionality in a Service-Oriented manner. Then, implement that functionality using the DLL.

Comment: Let's assume I already have a working DLL that makes calls to the database directly. I don't want that behaviour anymore. Instead I want to "route" all calls through a WCF Service. I'm thinking about how I can have the same namespaces. I guess by "design a service that exposes a coherent set of functionality in a Service-Oriented manner" you mean, that my wish for namespaces it not possible?

Comment: I mean you are making a mistake by "exposing" your DLL. Don't "expose a DLL". Write a service. _Use_ the DLL to implement the service. You'll probably find that the service you would design to perform the same functions as your DLL will have a very different interface than that of the DLL.

Comment: Ok, I agree on the point, that a DLL wrapping the service calls will be useful, if the parameters are different (e.g. the service calls need additional parameters, that the DLL implementing the service doesn't need to expose). But the main question remains: How do I organize the methods in the service. I don't want all methods like GetComments(...), GetFoo(), GetBar(), InsertComment(..), DeleteComment(...), ... to be methods of the client wcf object. I'd rather have a MyWCFClientObject.Comments. ... or a MyWCFClientObject.Foo. ... namespace.

Comment: Your question is really, "how do I design a service", and is the subject of whole books. My point is that this is a service design issue, not a namespace issue.